# Possible to serialize a collection that is part of an object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xml-serialization

Im trying to store my data in an XML file using the XML Serialization. Question is, if my object has a collection member, can i serialize the collection as well?

This is how my objects work.

```
class Project{
List<Iteration>
}

class Iteration{
List<Job>
}

class Job{
some other attributes
}
```

So each project has a list of iterations, and each iteration has a list of projects. So essentially, Each project can have many iterations and each iteration can have many jobs.

If serialization is not possible, can anyone suggest to me another method to store my data?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If `Iteration` and `Job` are serializable, then yes, you can serialize the entire `Project` data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have used such a type of serialization before.  If you have a simple application you can sometimes serialize your whole set of data from one root object (might be an antipattern somehow, but I know I have done it before).

This should work with the default XML serializer in the XML.Serialization namespace, but you need to make sure your classes are marked with the serializable attribute.  I'm not sure if it is available on the compact framework though.

Comment: Oh, and there are attributes you can add to your list properties for jobs, projects, and iterations that will help you control what the resulting xml will look.  I don't remember what they are called right now though.

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain it properly, What i want to know is, if i have an attribute that is a list, can i just pass for example a project object to be serialized into the xml file?

Comment: Yes.  It will serialize the project with it's properties, including the list of Iterations.  Each iteration serialized inside of the project will contain its own properties including the list of jobs.  Each job will be serialized with it's properties including any lists that it contains...and so on.\

Comment: Alright, one last question though, if i want to add a new project into the same XML file, can i serialize it the same way i did when first adding objects into the file? or will it overwrite the entire xml file?

Comment: Thats why you create a class called solution (or some other name which makes sense for you) which has a property which is a List<Project>....or you can just serialize a List<Project> instead of serializing a single Project.

Comment: I think a lot of the confusion here is because @Muhammad is referring to "attribute" when I think he means "member"...

Comment: Yeah I don't think you can have an 'attribute' that is a list.  Attributes are annotations on classes and properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx

Comment: @wllmsaccnt Serializing the whole dataset from a root object is certainly not an anti-pattern, in fact it's precisely the right thing to do! In this case the root object you mention is commonly called an "aggregate root".

Comment: @MattDavey That is a domain driven design view of it.  But I wasn't talking about serializing an aggregate root entity, I was talking about serializing all of the project data from a single root (which may or may not contain multiple levels of things that would be candidates for aggregate roots on their own).

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using Json serialization instead? If you use something like Json.Net (available for Windows Phone 7), you should be able to serialize the entire object graph.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but doesn't really have anything to do with what he is asking.  He is asking about capabilities of the xml serializer, how is suggesting JSON an answer?

Comment: Agreed, this is off topic. Xml is equally able to serialize an object graph.

Comment: Yeah, I was given that suggestion before, I chose xml cause i thought it'd be nice to learn something new, but this is a big headache, when the list of data is stored in the xml file, the last line in the xml file has about 12000 characters of the word nul and the xml cannot be deserialized :/, so im gonna go back to using text files, for the time being.

Comment: @Muhammad unless you have severe time constraints, you're not really doing yourself any favours by reverting back to a slightly more cumbersome approach just because you haven't yet quite grasped how to do XML serialization correctly :)